# Show that two lines intersect if and only if $a_1b_2 \ne a_2b_1$?

Tags: formal-proofs

Could anyone help me with this proof? Thanks

> Show that two distinct lines given by the equations $a_ix+b_iy+c_i=0$ for $i=1,2$ in $\mathbb R^2$ intersect if and only if $a_1b_2\ne a_2b_1$, and otherwise they are parallel in $\mathbb R^2$ but intersect at a point at infinity in $\mathbb P^2$.

Comment: Ummm, do you mean $a_1b_26!=a_2b_1$? Also, please elaborate about what you are trying to do, about what you have tried so far, and what you understand about the problem. It would behoove you to do so as you're more likely to get a good answer from us.

Comment: By the way Welcome to the site!

Comment: Hint: solve the system of two equations for the point of intersection. See when you get a unique solution, no solutions, or infinitely many (the latter being excluded by the premise that the lines are *distinct*).

Comment: Do not vandalize your post.  Show some respect to those who helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slopes of the two equations will be $-{a_1\over b_1}$ and $-{a_2\over b_2}$ respectively.

If $a_1b_2\neq a_2b_1$, then ${a_1\over b_1}\neq{a_2\over b_2}$ and $-{a_1\over b_1}\neq-{a_2\over b_2}$

Since the slopes are not equal, the lines are not parallel and must intersect.

However, if $a_1b_2 = a_2b_1$, then the slopes are equal, the lines must be parallel (since they are distinct), and they do not intersect.